# Add a value inline everytime on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to repeat an couple of items and every time it gets repeated it adds something like 10 to the value X.

So lets say I have

```
<rect ng-repeat="a in b"
x="0" y="0" fill="#00000" width="206.2"
height="117.7"
class=" {{ a.name }} "
/>
```

What i want to achieve is everytime it gets repeated it adds 10 to the X value, so first one is 0 than 10 than 20 than 30..

Comment: I guess you are to initialize a variable before that rectangle comes in, then increase its value. Curious to see how.

Comment: i thought something like the $index property on the ng-repeat https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat but can't get it to work it keeps error that it doesn't understand the math im trying to add to the X property

Comment: add a property in b object

Comment: I could do that, but is it not possible to do this inline ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do like this, it can help

```
<rect ng-repeat="a in b"
x="{{$index * 10}}" y="0" fill="#00000" width="206.2"
height="117.7"
class=" {{ a.name }} "
/>
```

Comment: That works :), but gives me alot of errors in my console haha, 'Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute x="{{$index * 10}}"'

Comment: your problem was that x should be incremented every time within loop is solved , Now I don't know what attributes values your <rect> directive take. Sorry :)

Comment: Found also the issue what throws the errors, if I use ng-attr-x="{{$index * 10 }}" it works perfectly without any errors

Comment: Thanks bro appreciate your help!